# Handle Exception in Python

Tags: python, try-catch

**Code:**

```
genders=[]
      for image in os.listdir('Face'):
        try:
          gender = int(image.split('_')[1])
        except ValueError:
          pass
      genders.append(gender)
```

Trying to add int values of string in list.
Raises Value error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

so for example : imageName_1 get that one and add to a list. but sometimes after _ there is no number. so i want to catch that image and delete it but don't want to stop the iteration.

Comment: Are you saying that you still get the `ValueError` even though you have `try:except:`? Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: can you share the sample filename

Comment: ```gender``` is defined only if ```try``` is executed successfully. Also, can you show the splitted list

Comment: You should put the `append()` call inside the `try`.

Comment: No, I Don't get the error but the loop stops.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Is the `append` call even inside the loop?

Comment: 24_1_0_20170117191400699.jpg this is the sample string which i want to split.

Comment: The error implies that there's a filename with two underscores in a row with nothing between them.

Comment: If there's no error, then what's the problem ? Does ```genders``` have any data after the loop ?

Comment: Please don't include stuff which doesn't happen in your question. What reason do you have to say that the loop stops?

Comment: genders=[]
for image in os.listdir('Face'):
  gender = int(image.split('_')[1])
  genders.append(gender)
  
this is the loop where i get valueError

Comment: Please decide whether you are asking about `ValueError` or about the loop stopping.

Comment: I am New at stackoverflow and i just can't properly add the question i think.

Comment: @quamrana Both. ValueError raises when i don't write try:except.

and loop stops when i write thy:except

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68911391/edit) your question with the question you want to ask.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the filename doesn't have any underscores in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **continue** statement will allow you to continue iteration.

```py
genders=[]
for image in os.listdir('Face'):
   try:
       gender = int(image.split('_')[1])
   except ValueError:
       continue
   genders.append(gender)
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a small change in the code will work

```
genders=[]
    for image in os.listdir('Face'):
        try:
            gender = int(image.split('_')[1])
            genders.append(gender)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
genders=[]
for image in os.listdir('Face'):
  try:
    genders.append(int(image.split('_')[1]))
  except (ValueError, IndexError):
    try:
      os.remove(image)
    except OSError:
      pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`gender` is defined in the try clause only, so you can't append it to `genders`, and you don't need to (because you want to delete the file), so this line should be in the `try` clause also:

```
genders=[]
for image in os.listdir('Face'):
    try:
        gender = int(image.split('_')[1])
        genders.append(gender)
    except ValueError:
        # delete file
        os.remove(image)
```

Comment: I did Exactly the same and it stopped iterating. i want to get that error remove the file and continue iteration

Comment: It's quite weird the iteration stopped, did the file deletion succeed or raised an exception?

Comment: Deletion succeed. but iteration stopped.  There is Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911539/15537942